# Can an EventHandler respond to events in batches?

Tags: c#, xaml, events, windows-phone-8

In my application, I have an event handler that listens for an event that tells it to update some UI.
This event is fired every time one an item is downloaded from a web service.

Is it possible to have the event handler delay processing these events until they stop firing (e.g. only update the UI three seconds after the last event was fired?)

<strike>My current plan is to record the time since last updating the UI from the event handler, and when it gets beyond a certain threshold, update it again, but I'm hoping there's something native in C# for this.</strike>
Edit: This wouldn't work because it relies on subsequent event to check the time, which would fail if I only get one event.

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this situation, since the events are identical. Essentially, they say, "Update the UI", not "Update the UI with this content"

Answer (score 2):

You can use RX extensions to do so.

The [Observable.Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229308%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method caches the events that arrive in the given time span and then gives you a flat list with all the sources.

```
Observable.Buffer(Observable.FromEvent(this, "DataUpdated"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
                  .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                  .Subscribe(e =>
                  {
                      // Do something here...
                  });
```

This will take all events for 3 seconds and the call the handler.

Comment: Sorry I copied code from a project with was using throttle and forgot to change it. Throttle ignores the values for the given time span, so that is not what you want.

Comment: This seems to be the right solution, but the lambda in the Subscribe function still gets called even when there weren't any events. Is there a way to have it only fire when there was at least one event?
The version of this function in WP8 seems to only have BufferOnCount and BufferOnTime

Answer (score 0):

I'd abstract things out a bit.  Use your event handler to put a record of event notifications in to a queue of event notifications.  Then, kick off a queue reader on another thread (call it method ReadEventQueue()) which:

1. Blocks any other calls to ReadEventQueue: Just set up a static variable of IsQueueReading.  Set it to true at the beginning of the ReadEventQueue method.  If the value is true at the beginning of the method, then exit out of the method without doing anything.
2. Read the first item in the queue (if it exists).
3. If the queue contained an item, then process the item and update your UI.
4. Sleep your queue reader thread for 3 seconds
5. Check the queue for additional items.  If it has any, go to step 3.  Else, exit and set IsQueueReading to false.